# Allegations of harassment by a faculty member and reporting?

Tags: sexual-misconduct, harassment

This issue is about a university in a third-world country.

I friend of mine, "Zelda," is a faculty member at a reputable university. During one of her sittings with an undergrad student, "Alice," she learned that another faculty member, "Thomas" is sending Alice some inappropriate text messages and emails.

Alice also mentioned that she has heard similar things from another student about Thomas. Alice offered to show some texts to Zelda, who refused, but told Alice the office of student affairs handles such matters. However, Alice is reluctant to report, and just wants to graduate ASAP, and thinks that Thomas might damage her, as he is quite powerful within school administration.

I am convinced that, given Alice is not the only student who is being harassed, "T" will misuse his position and will continue his inappropriate behavior. And I am also convinced that office of student affairs will take action, **if notified**. I guess that Zelda does not want to be a whistleblower, although she believe Alice.

I think that keeping quiet will only make things bad for other vulnerable students. Please mind that for a woman, going to university in that country is a privilege.

Thomas' behavior is not on the university's radar. So, I am thinking of dropping an anonymous email to office of student affairs. Is it OK to do such a thing? I have no affiliation with the university, Alice, or Thomas.

**Is it OK for someone, who has nothing to do with Alice, to drop an email asking administration to take a look into these allegations?**

Comment: A compelling question, a difficult question, and very dependent on many specifics of the situation... Also, anonymous allegations have problems with credibility, and perhaps even legal issues (e.g., in the U.S., accused people are generally allowed to know their accusers...) A bad situation, but/and also tricky.

Comment: In some places, such as where I am, there are local dignity at work representatives, part of whose role is to support those who don't want to make a complaint.  Do you have anyone similar?  If the student in question doesn't want to talk to them, you (or Z) still can, without the need to name names at least at first

Comment: I support your idea, but you must be very very careful. In some cases, if the university finds out Z was involved, and someone in the school administration is as immoral as T, then things can get very bad for Z. So if you are not sure how things will turn out, you would do well to not only be anonymous but also try to ensure that the complaint cannot be traced to Z, including telling Z to not reveal that she told you anything. Reputability of the school is an **unreliable** indicator that the school will do what is morally right; they may protect their reputation but not their students.

Comment: See: http://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/real-life/true-stories/full-list-of-universities-exposed-by-sexual-assault-investigation/news-story/f7c39dcacce8a9c839bc8b881172173b, https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/02/09/baylor-not-alone-shielding-athletes-accused-misconduct-punishment, https://www.theguardian.com/education/2017/mar/05/students-staff-uk-universities-sexual-harassment-epidemic, https://www.mercurynews.com/2017/11/30/stanford-sexual-misconduct-revelation-exposes-storied-professors-secret,

Comment: https://www.mercurynews.com/2017/12/07/in-university-sexual-harassment-cases-a-chilling-power-dynamic.

Comment: Not only is it okay, in the US it is manditory requirement for a faculty members to report issues of sexual harrassment (part of something called Title IX) they hear about from students.

Comment: @Kimball:  Under the law, US institutions are required only to make a clearly-defined policy about who is a "mandatory reporter" under Title IX.  But many US institutions, including mine, include almost everyone in that category (with some exceptions such as chaplains & health professionals), so the effect is much the same.

Comment: @Kimball this was apparently in a 3rd world country so your comment makes very much sense.

Comment: I would suggest instead of using letters, to use whole made-up names, which are much easier to read and follow.

Comment: I think your post would be a little easier to follow if you chose some fake names instead of using letters. E.g., Z could be Zelda, A could be Alice, T could be Tom, B could be Barbara. If you want a little more randomization of the names, you could use [this generator](https://www.behindthename.com/random/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As [Allure](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/84834/allure) points out, opinions on this matter will vary, so let me note some points that I think are important here, and also offer an opinion that is slightly to the contrary of some other answers.  (For brevity, these points are framed as an answer to the person you are talking about who is the academic dealing with these students.)

- **Academics have a duty of care to students:** Students at university are adults, but they mostly are still young and inexperienced.  In my humble opinion, academics should generally err on the side of *pushing for assistance* in cases like these, even if the students are reluctant.  Students are generally young adults who may be intimidated by the positions and standing of older adults who have attained academic success and institutional power.  Having another academic push the matter forward may be helpful in overcoming this disparity.
- **Harassers thrive on the "I won't make a fuss" mentality:** Without making any assumption about whether or not harassment has actually occurred in this case, it is worth noting that cases of harassment tend to be done over and over again by a small number of individuals, and tend to proliferate because each person who is being harassed thinks it is only them, and they don't want to make a fuss and risk retribution by a powerful person.  In cases where a victim of harassment reports the conduct, it is not unusual for this to precipitate an avalanche of other allegations against the same harasser.  Recent events in Hollywood (e.g., Harvey Weinstein) testify to this fact, as do many other cases of sexual harassment.
- **Merely referring an allegation is not "accusatory":** Reporting an allegation *for it to be investigated* need not presume the truth of the allegation, and need not be "accusatory".  That is the point of an investigation - to get to the truth from a starting point of it being unknown.  It is perfectly legitimate to report allegations you have heard on to the administration, while taking no position on whether they are true or false, but still asking the university to consider whatever investigation into the matter is warranted by the allegations.  There is no contradiction between wanting to bring this matter to the attention of the administration, and also wanting to avoid a false accusation.  Just make sure that if you do send an email to the administration, you write it in a neutral way that does not presume that misconduct has occurred.
- **In the end, evidence will be required:** While it is legitimate to report hearsay allegations for the purpose of bringing a matter to the attention of the administration, you should bear in mind that your hearsay is not evidence.  Unless one of the affected students is willing to speak to the university administration about this, the university will probably be very limited in its ability to investigate the matter.  That is perfectly legitimate - after all, people should not be subject to negative proceeding against them without evidence, and hearsay evidence is weak evidence.
- With this in mind, the contribution you can make here is to bring the allegation to the attention of the administration, leading to contact with the students, and giving them an opportunity to report this matter formally.  By acting as the initial referrer of the allegation, you can also show your students that actions are louder than words - you are willing to get involved, so maybe that will make them more willing.  Still, at the end of the day it will depend on them.  In my view even this step might be a good idea, even if the students ultimately decide not to proceed.  I don't agree with the recommendation to do nothing.
- **Have the courage to put your name to the referral:** Think carefully about whether it is appropriate to report this *anonymously*.  If it is justifiable to refer the matter to the university administration, and if you frame your email in a fair way that does not presume misconduct, then you ought to have the courage to put your name to it, and stand by your own actions.  Reports of harassment are generally treated in confidence (at least up to the point where the accused is able to face the accusations), and this is an opportunity to set an example for your students and show that you are willing to act on your own principles.  If a grown-up academic can't show the backbone to make a report about a colleague, without hiding behind anonymity, why should younger students show the courage that is absent in their elders?

Anyway, that is my two-cents.  I can see that there are others with contrary opinions and I think their answers are also reasonable, though not what I would do.  It may be helpful to consider all these different ideas on this matter before making your decision.

Comment: Very well written answer. I agree with everything that you wrote. But I would like to point out that you missed one point. I am not connected to those students and university. My friend teaches there and she is not interested in getting involved. I am an unrelated person in the whole story but I think that is not an excuse for me to do nothing.

Comment: But still everything you said is applicable. All your points make sense.

Comment: Fair enough.  For brevity, I framed the answer more as an answer to the person who is actually involved, mainly to make it easier to read.  If you are another step removed from that, then the answer is really written to the person you're talking about.  If I had to frame the answer as an answer to a person who knows a person who knows a person, it would have involved a lot of annoying circumlocutions!

Comment: I have edited to add a parenthetic remark prior to my dot points, to make that clear in the post.

Comment: I think you’re strictly wrong when you say that a report of an allegation isn’t an accusation: it pretty much by definition is (and “I’m just reporting what I heard” is an ineffective excuse: the effect is the same). Still, that’s a minor language issue and I agree with your recommendations.

Comment: It is still an accusation *from the person who made the accusation*, but it need not be an accusation from the party that is passing on the report.  To say it is an "excuse" means that you don't accept that a person may ever legitimately pass on an accusation without investing it with their own acceptance.  If I go to a HR department to report some misconduct, and the administrator there says, "I'm not the right person to take your report, but I'll pass it on to the HR manager" does that mean that this administrator is now the one making an "accusation"?  Is her denial just an "excuse"?

Comment: @Ben No, I totally accept that (in fact, my comment explicitly said that I agree with your recommendation, which includes passing on an accusation). But by passing on the accusation they *are* propagating it. It’s tautological.

Comment: I understand we're in agreement over the substantive issues, so that is totally fine.  But regarding the language, I never claimed that the allegation is not being propagated.  Propagation of an allegation is appropriate in many cases.  The point I am making is that it is possible (and indeed common) for a person passing on an allegation to do so in a neutral way, such that the allegation remains an allegation only by the original complainant, and does not also become an allegation of the person passing it on.  I agree that it is still an accusation from the original complainant.

Comment: @Ben It's not about brevity, it's about addressing the correct dilemma: OP is not asking for advice to give their friend, but for advice for _themselves_ regarding what _he or she_ should do.

Comment: @Pandora: In that case my advice would be for him to consider the advice I have written for the friend, and if he agrees with it, to pass it on.  I think the matter becomes excessively complicated if we try to give advice to someone to give advice to someone to give advice to someone.

Comment: Good, but I cannot fully agree. 1. Neither the OP nor the friend have read the text messages and are not in a position to judge if the content was inappropriate. A Cambridge professor I knew, in his 80s, called all female students "little virgins" openly and no-one seemed to mind. Judgement needs to be based on facts. 2. Denunciations by third party (anonymous or not) were the foundations of McCarthyism and the Cultural revolution. It's not acceptable. 3. Not enough is made of the fact that this is taking place in a third world country. 4. My uni cleared married prof who gave student VD...

Comment: Your point (1) is in agreement with my third dot point.  Because the person in question is only hearing this second-hand (and probably does not know all the evidence) it is appropriate for them to refer it in a neutral manner that does not presume misconduct and does not re-assert the allegation as their own allegation.  There is no "denunciation" of a third party; only a referral of an allegation to the proper authority to hear it.

Comment: @Ben, I think you're missing the point: OP considers to interfere, even if Z will not. Hence it's not about what advice to pass on to Z, but what OP should do if Z does not want to do anything (as seems to be the case).

Comment: If there are text messages, then there is hard evidence. If the student is worried about graduation, they can keep the evidence and report it after they leave.

Answer (score 13):

This is going to vary massively based on opinion. Still, my reaction is to **do nothing**. A or B have to stand up for themselves, otherwise for others it's a case of wanting to help but not being able to do so. Imagine what happens if an uninvolved third party writes to the administration asking them to act:

1. The administration has to take the allegations seriously. To convince them of that, you need to provide evidence. It seems like you don't have any solid evidence, only 2nd-hand information.
2. Assuming the administration takes the allegations seriously, they're likely to want to interview A and B. If A and B refuse to cooperate, the administration can't proceed.
3. For the administration to proceed, they need to make A and B cooperate even though they've stated (at least in A's case she has) that they don't want to. Are you sure that you want to put them through this?

Another thing to mention is that you could be accused of betrayal of trust. Z can plausibly argue that she told you this expecting that you will keep it confidential (it is likely A told Z expecting Z to keep it confidential, too). If you report to the administration and they press you about this, what can you say?

I would talk to A & B, argue that they should raise the issue to the administration both for themselves and for others, but also defer to their decision.

Comment: In addition to encouraging them, the OP may want to offer to accompany them and participate with the process as a means of supporting them. In the same vein as Ben's last point, this indicates that the OP is willing to put their reputation on the line to help.

Comment: I entirely disagree with this. Even if the administration cannot find evidence to actually do anything about it *this time*, then the issue has still been recorded. If this keeps happening, at the very least it must become clear to people that it is not an isolated incident. If nobody ever reports things, the accused can make any single report look like it's someone with an ax to grind, and dismiss it as a case of he-said-she-said. That's so much harder if there have already been a dozen reports, even if none of the accusers is willing to talk.

Comment: I think if a person _suspects_ (even without proof) that a crime is being committed, they are ethically responsible to pass whatever information they have to whoever could investigate the matter further. Sexual harassment (if that's what the "inappropriate messages" are) is a crime, and should not be the victim's responsibility to deal with. Additionally, perhaps A is reluctant to speak up, but would do it if approached by authorities directly.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth even if there are a dozen reports, if none of the accusers are willing to talk, what can the administration possibly do? Any action at all would be presuming the accused is guilty.

Comment: @Pandora A is an adult, and she has already stated she does not want to speak up. To think "perhaps she'll change her mind" is something I'd find excessively rude if I were A. The message is that you think you know what I want better than I do.

Comment: @Allure: Employment is often at the discretion of an employer. So, while it requires actual proof to convict someone in court, a "preponderance of evidence" may be enough to not renew someone's job contract. And having a dozen, independent reports of the same thing, even if none of the women are willing to put their names next to a report, is a *preponderance of evidence*, in particular if these reports were all made without one knowing about the other.

It is true that employment of tenured professors works differently, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Allure: A lesson of the #metoo movement is that it is exceedingly difficult for many people to report abuse. But that it is liberating to know that many others have felt the same abuse. So an administrator may not succeed in convincing a single victim to come forward and testify, but the administrator may be successful if they can say "You are not alone. You will testify alongside 15 other women who have experienced the same as you have. Your voice will be heard because there are *many* voices."

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth not an expert with law, but I suspect the person can file for wrongful dismissal if his contract isn't renewed, arguing that there is no firm evidence. As for the administration convincing victims to come forward and testify, that's uncomfortably close to presuming guilt to me. If one doesn't assume that the person is guilty, then why is one attempting to gather evidence of guilt? More neutral would be to say, "if you testify we can investigate, if you do nothing we can't proceed. It's your choice."

Comment: Anyway as I wrote, this varies massively based on one's personal values. I would do nothing myself, but I would also not stop someone else from filing a report with the administration.

Comment: @Allure My point is that the issue is not just between A and T, it seems to include other women (who might not know they have options to deal with it, or who are too afraid to do something by themselves). A has her right not to testify, but I think it is unethical of external observers to keep it to themselves. Also, I think it's better to err on the side of caution: As long as the investigation is conducted discreetly, it is better to investigate and find the person not guilty, than it is to let a possible sex offender keep his job and inappropriately interact with students.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you *can* do anything, ethically. At least not in the way you are considering.

You write that "accusing anyone wrongly has serious consequences",
and "students and the university will be at the receiving end",
but have you considered the consequences for the student "A"
and for your friend "Z"?

The student "A" has said that she does not
want the stress and possible problems that
reporting the faculty member "T"
would cause. Maybe she *should* report him,
for the sake of other students, but she has decided that she doesn't
want to, or perhaps can't. Do you want to force her to this,
possibly even ruining her education? Who knows how she will react?
It should be her choice, not yours,
so you shouldn't name her.

Your friend "Z" didn't want to see the evidence, and doesn't want
to get involved. "Z" has made a similar decision as "A", for
unknown reasons. Again, her choice, not yours.

It seems to me that what your anonymous letter
should then say is something like this:

> Hi, I am an unidentified person, who heard from an unidentified
>   faculty member at your university that an unidentified student
>   at the university claims that faculty member "T" is sending
>   harassing text messages.

I don't think that will be very helpful.

You *can*, however, encourage your friend to take a more active interest, and try to get the student to report the harasser, perhaps waiting until after she has graduated.

Comment: Waiting until she has graduated sounds reasonable, until you realize that T is probably doing this to every batch of students, so there will always be a 'current victim' that might be affected by any attempt to investigate T. I do agree it's difficult to maintain total anonymity and provide any useful information, so the asker is going to have to find some compromise.

Comment: @user21820 that assumes that the story is true.  The OP has no first-hand knowledge ("I saw T do these things") of any wrongdoing, nor even second-hand ("A told me that T did these things"). This is third-hand ("Z said A said that T did"), which is also known as "hearsay" and "gossip".   ["Thank you, Simone" scene from Ferrus Bueller's Day Off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swBtLPWeKbU ]

Comment: @MontyHarder: Almost everything we do is based on second-hand knowledge. But it's **statistically true** that sexual offenses are very commonly carried out by predators. For you to dismiss the asker's question as hearsay and gossip suggests that you are or wish to be ignorant of the incredible prevalence of abuse of power everywhere, because no sane person would want to report such things without a vested interest (as the asker does) unless he/she believes it is true to some extent. If a friend of mine has never once lied to me, I would be inclined to believe other things she says. Same here.

Comment: @ user21820...since "A" claims that multiple students are in similar situation, waiting for A to graduate wont make much difference. There will always be someone who would be a current student.

Comment: @user21820 I'm calling it hearsay and gossip because that's what it is. With each retelling, some bit of the truth can be lost, and some embellishments creep in.  Statistics are not sufficient to convict someone of a crime.  We require actual evidence for that, and sane legal systems recognize the weakness of hearsay/gossip.  It may be more likely that T is guilty than that he is innocent of the specific offenses alleged, but the fact that neither A nor Z is willing to testify under penalty of perjury to that effect means that the OP should be very careful about spreading such stories.

Comment: @NAASI: That's **exactly my point**, which is **why** I implied in my very first comment that "perhaps waiting until after she has graduated" is not as reasonable as it sounds.

Comment: @MontyHarder: I did not say it counts as **evidence**. I'm only saying that you are wrong to call it just "gossip", which frankly demeans the victims of the many attacks that continuously occur everywhere. But I **agree** with you (I never disagreed) that one should be very careful about informing the administration of such a story. I commented only because I do not quite agree that waiting until after the student has graduated is frequently not ideal, unless you think that it is a one-off harassment.

Comment: @user21820 Stating the plain fact that it's gossip/rumor/hearsay doesn't demean any victims. It makes no statement about them whatsoever. It is simply a description of the epistemological difference between "I saw T do H" and "Z said that A said that T did H".  The fact that many people in positions of power abuse their power provides exactly zero information about whether T abused his power against A. I agree that waiting until A graduates is a bad idea, because the longer someone waits to tell a story, the more doubt there will be of its veracity. Statutes of Limitation exist for good reason

Comment: @MontyHarder: Then we agree on everything except the English word "gossip". I learned that word as having connotations of exaggeration or twisting, but if you don't mean that then that's fine. I suspect other people may misconstrue your statement in the same way I did, though. And also, thanks for mentioning the Statute of Limitation, as a concrete reason (besides my pragmatic reason) for not delaying unnecessarily.

Comment: @user21820 I used it in precisely the sense of the game "Gossip" (also known as "Telephone") in which one person tells something to a second, who repeats it to a third, etc., each of whom is trying to retell the story as faithfully as possible (without any exaggeration or twisting) but by the time it gets to the last person in the chain, everyone gets a good laugh out of just how different it is from the original.

Comment: @MontyHarder: Ah. I'd never heard of that game being called "Gossip", but rather "broken telephone". Anyway I'm glad the miscommunication is cleared up! Ironic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok for a person, who has nothing to do with any of characters in the story, to drop an email asking administration to take a look into these allegations?

Since the country isn't listed, there is no way to provide any definitive legal or even cultural answer to this question.

However, aside from any legal or cultural specifics, this is a matter of conscience for "Z" to deal with personally. "Z" should consider whether they can live with their decision after considering the possible ramifications of their decision.

- If "Z" does nothing, is "Z" prepared to accept that there may be future students that will be subject to such harassment that could have been prevented?
- If "Z" does nothing, is "Z" prepared to accept that such harassment (either now or in the future) may escalate beyond inappropriate texts/emails that could have been prevented?
- Is "Z" prepared for the possibility that this becomes a public scandal in the future and that "A" may make public statements that they confided in "Z" and that "Z" did nothing?

If "Z" cannot comfortably answer yes to these questions, they really should report the allegations to the office of student affairs.